# How to automate toggle button using Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automation, junit5, nebular

How to automate the toggle button using selenium? How to find the path? Please help me.

Here the code for the nb-toggle selector. What should I get to use Selenium Automation? I took xpath, cssSelector. Any solution?

```
<div _ngcontent-pnv-c15="" class="custom-control custom-switch">
   <input _ngcontent-pnv-c15="" class="custom-control-input" type="checkbox"id="6045c1fe1c189e17311821aa">
<label _ngcontent-pnv-c15="" class="custom-control-label" for="6045c1fe1c189e17311821aa">
    :before
    :after
</label>
</div>
```

[image: toggle button]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
WebElement checkbox = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[type='checkbox']"));
checkbox.click();
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to interact with the toggle button through the surrounding parent element:

```
WebElement togName = driver.findElement(By.className("custom-control"));
togName.click();
```